# Zoopla property listing API returns "Unknown location" using python and requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, get, python-requests

I am trying to retrieve the property listing using Python 3 and the requests library. For some reason, the API returns error code 7 "Unknown location entered". The same parameters seems to work well on Zoopla's [IO-Docs](https://developer.zoopla.co.uk/io-docs) where results are returned.
My request:

```
import requests
api_key = xxxxxxxxx

r3 = requests.get("https://api.zoopla.co.uk/api/v1/property_listings",data = {'area':'Oxford','api_key':api_key})'
```

The request returns the following:

```
print(r3.request.url) --> https://api.zoopla.co.uk/api/v1/property_listings

print(r3.request.body)' --> area=Oxford&api_key=xxxxxxxxx

print("Status code:",r3.status_code)' --> Status code: 400

print(r3.content)' -->b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" >\n<response>\n <error_code>7</error_code>\n <error_string>Unknown location entered.</error_string>\n</response>\n'
```

I don't understand why it returns "Unknown location" while the same parameters work fine on their website. Can anyone help, please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When using the `data` parameter your data get submitted in the body of the request, as you have demonstrated in your question. Since this is a GET request, the body is propably ignored.

Instead, you should send your data in the query string with the `params` parameter.

```
import requests

api_key = 'xxxxxxxxx'
api_url = 'https://api.zoopla.co.uk/api/v1/property_listings.xml'
data = {'area':'Oxford','api_key':api_key}
r3 = requests.get(api_url, params=data)

print(r3.request.url)
print(r3.request.body)
```

---

```
'https://api.zoopla.co.uk/api/v1/property_listings.xml?area=Oxford&api_key=xxxxxxxxx'
None
```